# Пакет, создающий таблицу в БД при установке

Tags: веб-программирование, laravel

Задача звучит так - создать пакет (packege для Laravel), который при установке сгенерит нужные таблицы в БД.
Как это сделать?

я новичек в веб-разработке, и потому пока нет даже общего видения куда копать, поиски в интернете привели к пониманию - что таблицы создаются при помощи миграций, миграции можно генерить пакетом, и запускать руками из командной строки???. Например тут http://jean179.ru/sajt-vizitka-na-laravel-etap-5-sozdanie-tablic-v-baze-dannyx/

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "пакет"? rpm- (deb-) пакет или что-то иное?

Comment: @aleks.andr package в Laravel. Это пакет, который устанавливается в данный фрейморк, и добавляет сайту функционал. соответственно пользователь должен взять пакет, установить его себе в laravel и в БД должно все необходимые таблицы используемы пакетом возникнуть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакет у вас, я думаю, имелось ввиду написать свой набор классов который бы включал в себя Сервис провайдер, маршруты, миграции и файл конфигураций.

Все достаточно подробно описано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages)

Если что-то, не понятно, можно всегда посмотреть в готовые пакеты на github:

Я бы посоветовал вам, взглянуть на то, как устроены пакеты такие как [entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust), [laravel-sitemap](https://github.com/RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap), [blog](https://github.com/serverfireteam/blog)

Так же можно посмотреть на статьи, которые описывают этот вопрос детально
[laravel-5-package-in-10-easy-steps](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-a-laravel-5-package-in-10-easy-steps/)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно создать серверный (MySQL?) скрипт, который создаёт необходимую структуру - БД, таблицы-индексы-связи, процедуры-функции-триггеры, пользователи-пароли-права. Тот же скрипт должен заполнять данными предопределённые таблицы (всякие справочники - стран, единиц измерения и пр.). Само собой в скрипте должны выполняться все мыслимые проверки с необходимыми ветвлениями и обработками.

Далее нужно средствами развёртывания пакета создать сценарий, который получит сведения о сервере, включая информацию о подключении к нему и аутентификации, соединится с ним, запустит на исполнение созданный скрипт и проконтролирует его выполнение, а в случае проблем - предпримет необходимые действия по их устранению. Этот сценарий запускается как составная часть процесса установки пакета после выполнения всех пререквизитных действий.

Это общая методика. В зависимости от конкретных средств развёртывания в него могут вноситься изменения и дополнения.

Comment: да, MySQL. а разве нельзя создать пакет, который не зависимо от скриптов на сервере сам добавит таблицы, необходимые пакету для работы? Я раньше пользовалась Joomla - там просто ставишь на "читстый" фреймворк пакет и все необходимые таблицы в бд пакет себе создает.

Comment: Средства развёртывания пакетов расширения Laravel мне незнакомы. Так что ответа на этот вопрос я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать файл-шаблон .sql, затем средствами PHP прописать его в базу.

Попробуйте сначала в phpmyadmin или в другой программе сделайте всю необходимую структуру базы, сделайте экспорт в формат sql.

Затем читайте как с помощью PHP залить структуру БД из файла .sql

В общем то по PHP всё очень подробно описано, проблем быть не должно.

Файл-шаблон .sql должен находится там же, где всё сырьё для вашей задачи.

Comment: Создание БД в приложении и создание миграций в приложении - это уже сделано. Надо именно при добавлении пакета в это приложение создать дополнительную таблицу в существующей бд. Кажется накопала в оф. документации https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages